# How can I trap records that I inserted using tableadapter to avoid record duplication?

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is the tableadapter I used. Now in this code I want to trap the username if it exist or not in the database. How can I do that? I am new in tableadapter so its hard for me to solve this problem.

```
 TblGradesUserTableAdapter1.Insert(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, userType)
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by trapping the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new query in the same table adapter and then `SELECT count` of the certain username the it will return the count of the username

you can do this for example

```
Dim n as int = TblGradesUserTableAdapter1.CheckUserName(txtUsername.Text)

If n = 0 then
// insert the record
Else
//messagebox the duplicate
End if
```

Comment: Thanks you! Its working, but I also did that and this problem is solved.. .thanks anyway!